# Can I Build my app within a week with Supersonic UI ( AppGyver )

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, yeoman, hybrid-mobile-app, supersonic

So here's my problem . I have a web app designed in `code-igniter php` and we're exposing an API for it to talk to a mobile app.

It's an education based CMS app. It allows teachers and students to log in and see grades and any calendar based notifications

We want to quickly build an app which will let students log in and see their notifications or messages . I am sort of a front-end developer and was looking into Ionic and AppGyver's Supersonic UI ?

What would be the best choice to go for now ( I need something within a week ), also , how do I set up my app folder to talk with the api or bind it with the api ?

I've not really worked with APIs a whole lot and a bit lost in how to set up my project. I come from a graphic design background and have been recently using Yeoman for my front-end workflow.

We plan to migrate from code-igniter to `AngularJS` in the long run , so `Ionic` would be a good choice then but for now I need to get a working app and was wondering if `SuperSonic UI` would be a better choice for an hybrid app.

Questions :

1. From what I've described what would be the best solution to go forward with?
2. Also, can anyone suggest any tutorials / screencast which does an in-depth project with one of the technologies ? Or maybe some other frameworks I've not taken into account ?
3. Can I set it up with Yeoman ? Can I use Yeoman and Ionic together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appgyver is doing well with Supersonic and Data. They are working extensively on their Data implementations. I am currently using an API for my application without using Appgyver Data, but also was able to get it working with their data option. They have a few tutorials to get you the basics of building, scaffolding, deploying applications using their framework.

[Tutorials](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/tutorial/)

You will notice the third tutorial gets you into the data portion.

This is the [documentation](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/data/setting-up-appgyver-database/) for their data options.

What you will see in their framework is AngularJS written in either coffeescript or javascript (you choose which when you first run `steroids create projectName` in your command line).

There are lots of discussions about this platform happening [here](http://community.appgyver.com/).

Personally, I am about to release an application to the app store and google play with little effort. Your application doesn't sound too complicated if you have an API to get the data. This is worth a shot.

They also have a new product coming out May 25th I am told. And with lots of funding recently, they are hiring more developers to tackle the [GitHub](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids) issues and move the platform forward rapidly.

I've only had good experiences with them.

Yeoman is being used behind the scenes as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks for the advice , I'm delving into AppGyver for now. Although , I've had a problem. So I wanted to use fontawesome and I've gone ahead and saved it using bower install -g fontawesome --save but it's not showing any icons . I can't even get supersonicons to show up. I'm following their pattern of using super instead of ion as a prefix for class name . Still nothing.

Comment: Can you post a question on the [Muut forum](https://muut.com/appgyver#!/) and we can talk further on there?

Comment: @area28 The forum at Muut is responding with 404 not found! do you know why?